# New controls added to Form are not shown when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, windows-forms-designer

I'm facing a problem of adding new controls on a form. 
While adding controls on my form, I'm normally able to edit them and work with them in `.cs` files.

When I'm debugging, all new added controls vanish, as well as implementations (like properties) for old controls, and old controls, which were deleted, are still shown.

I have already deleted `bin` and `obj`. Problem still appears.

Searching for help!
Cheers

Edit: I checked other projects which are using windows forms too, and in those everything works fine

Comment: Have you verified that the new controls are added to the `Designer.cs` file? ..and if you re-open the solution, the problem still exists?

Comment: Hello @JLe, yes they are added to the Designer.cs file. If i add a text to a control, it is also added to the designer of the given form.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, are you using the "Save All" button to save your progress and then debug it ? 
If your program is running without problems in debugger but is showing old things, maybe you havent saved your progress ?

Comment: Hey @John Linaer, i saved it several times, closed the project and restarted it. Problem persists :/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

If you have opened your project, click on top "Create" and then on the task "create new -projectname-".
VS needs some seconds for running through the task but after that all implemented controls and task that has not been shown are going to appear. Furthermore all properties etc.